# testing django: reason for unexpected http status code

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, httprequest

We have many unitests in our django application.

But if a tests fails because the status code does not match:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo_eins_di514/src/foo-time/foo_time/tests/EditTest.py", line 813, in test_web_entry_with_unclassified_activity
    self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code, url)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 494, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 487, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: /foo_eins_di514/modtime/calendar/entry/view/172/
```

.... it is completly unknown where the wrong exit status gets created.

I big applications it can take some time to find the root of the problem where the exist status gets created, since the exit status can get created in a middleware, too.

Any hint how to make this more testable?

The test looks like this:

```
url=reverse(view_name, kwargs=dict(id=entry.id))
response=client.get(url)
self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code, url)
```

Comment: First, can you post an example test... might allow folks to suggest how to better make things unit tests.  Secondly, for me personally, I find that if I'm getting back a 200, I rarely specifically check for status_code == 20, but instead do self.assertContains(response,"some text I'm looking for"), which implicitly also does a 200 check.  YMMV.

Comment: @Foon I added the relevant snippet of the test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you should split your tests up into proper unit tests and test smaller units of code.  Use Django's [request factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/) and test only the view code.  Or split your view into smaller functions and test them individually.

Using Django's test client is more of an integration test than a unittest as it tests url routing, database, middleware, templates etc

Answer (score 4):

You replaced the useful message from `assertEqual` with a less usefull message, namely the URL that failed (third argument to `assertEqual`).

You have done this because the same test method tests multiple URLs. That is a bad practice. Each test method should test one thing.  DRY doesn't apply to unit-testing (or at least it is more important that each test method test one thing, and one thing only).

Say you knew the offending status code, it would be more obvious to find from where it stemmed. Say it was 404, well then, perhaps the object was not found, perhaps it was 300-something, perhaps you don't have proper permissions and are being redirected to a login page.

Any real programming error would fail with a normal exception and a useful stacktrace.

If you are concerned with the logic inside a particular view, split the logic into multiple testable units.

In this particular case, my money would be on bad PK or missing permissions though.

Regarding your mocking, try something like:

```
with patch.object(HttpResponseBase, '__init__', None):
    response = client.get(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this solution to find the problem:

```
import django
django.http.response.HttpResponseBase.__init__=None
response=client.get(url)
```

This results in a stacktrace, where I can see where the HttpResponse was created.

Of course this is just a temporary solution for debugging. I tried the same with mock, but this failed since I am not a mock expert (yet).